# How do we print characters line by line and save it to csv or text file in PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

1. DECLARE
2. V_NUMBER NUMBER :=23;
3. BEGIN
4. LOOP
5. V_NUMBER:=V_NUMBER+1;
6. EXIT WHEN V_NUMBER:=25;
7. --Some kind of function to be applied for printing and nesting lines into CSV or TEXT file.
8. END LOOP;
9. COMMIT;
10. END;

Comment: Please add some more details about the problem like what kind of data should be written and is this an ad-hoc job or a job to be scheduled?

Comment: Well I simply want to print data into 25 lines after I rerun same block it should start with 26th line and no, it's neither ad-hoc job nor job to be scheduled.
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

### Scripting an Oracle SQL Query for Creating a CSV or Text Typed File Output

Consider running this from a SQL Plus session and use the `SPOOL` command.  All output of the SQL command that follows will be written to the file name you specify.

> If you need to append your results each successive time the SQL commands are run, then an OS level command would work appropriately when invoking this sqlplus executable block of PL/SQL:

**Where the file name of this script is: "sample_csv_out.sql"**

```
DECLARE
     v_total_columns constant number:= 3; -- Number of columns queried
     v_column_counter   number;
     
     v_csv_record   varchar2(1000);
     c_csv_column_format   constant   varchar2(15):= 
        '<<COLUMN1_VAL>>,<<COLUMN2_VAL>>,<<COLUMN3_VAL>>';

     cursor result_cur is
        SELECT column1, column2, column3
          FROM tablea
         WHERE column1 = ... ;

BEGIN

  v_csv_record:= 'COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_csv_record);

     FOR i in result_cur LOOP
        v_csv_record:= replace(c_csv_column_format, '<<COLUMN1_VAL>>', i.column1);
        v_csv_record:= replace(v_csv_record, '<<COLUMN2_VAL>>', i.column2);
        v_csv_record:= replace(c_csv_record, '<<COLUMN3_VAL>>', i.column3);

        dbms_output.put_line(v_csv_record);

     END LOOP; 

END;
```

So, for example in a WINDOWS O/S environment, the call to append the output to a specific file name would be:

```
 C:\> sqlplus sample_csv_out.sql >> mycsv_out.csv
```

The `>>` notation instructs the operating system to pipe the output of running `sample_csv_out.sql` via a sqlplus session.

The command `DBMS_OUTPUT` does the rest.  If you need more details, see more [Oracle documentation on DBMS_OUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm).

**COMMENTS:**  I chose the `RECORD STRING TEMPLATE` approach to make this script a little more flexible and reusable.  I recommend to keep any data manipulation logic within the `CURSOR` statement. Often when the two are mixed, it gets harder to debug any typos in syntax within a long string of values.

The construction of an output record was also designed to reduce typos, mistakes and frustration... if there are more than 3 columns in your own scripts, adding another element to the output string is mostly a cut-and-paste operation. Likewise with the "header" row (column titles).

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write files in PL/SQL using the UTIL_FILE package

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

Comment: Yeah I know utl_file package will be use...but how it will be save , so next time I run it should continue with last line i.e "End of File".

Comment: If you know of the UTIL_FILE package then you should also know there is an `append` mode when you open the file.